# Can we consider the multiverse as the capstone of the Copernican Revolution?

Tags: metaphysics, cosmology

The Copernican Revolution was a major shift in our mindset as a species. No longer were we the special center of the universe. If we generalize this notion, we see it surface in many areas beyond physics and cosmology.

We can call this broader notion the

> **Generalized Copernican Principle**: Nothing is sui generis.

1. Life is just the proper confluence of (lifeless) physiochemical conditions.
2. Humans are but the latest iteration of one of many branches of the phylogenetic tree
3. We orbit a star that is just like countless others
4. Our galaxy is a middling galaxy among countless galaxies
5. Euclidean geometry is just one of an infinite variety of possible geometries
6. Our "now" is one of an infinite number of "nows" depending on relative motion
7. Physics looks the same regardless of your state of motion

and so on...

Each of these discoveries basically "took us down a notch" from being special to being ordinary. It seems that the natural conclusion of this line of thinking is that even this universe/reality we experience isn't privileged/special; that there are countless realities out there, that whatever can happen is does happen in at least one reality.

In a way, this feels like the most complete type of reality, since we are not limiting it to our particular history of this particular universe/reality. What is there that really would stop being (unconstrained) from realizing every single facet of itself?

Given the above, is the link between Copernican ideas and the multiverse something that has been written about before? Are there alternatives?

Comment: In the penultimate section: do you mean "not limiting it by(!) our"? also the section before "whatever can happen does happen"? What does mean the second sentence of the penultimate section?

Comment: The multiverse has so many meanings to different people, that whatever we unwrap next, could be considered as multiverse, perhaps you could be more specific?

Comment: That description of the Copernican revolution is tendentious and unhistorical. Before the Copernican revolution, the Earth was not considered the pinnacle of the universe, but the bottom of it. In both Greek and Christian thought, the heavens were higher, better, perfect. Angels and gods were superior to men. If you insist on putting values on a scientific theory, it would be more accurate to say that the Copernican revolution raised humans up by showing that all matter in the universe is the same so the earth and humans aren't especially mundane.

Comment: One conceivable highly speculative alternative could be more drastic than your David Lewis modal realism like proposal, all these multiverses could actually co-exist simultaneously relative to us within our single universe in some entangled causal way...

Comment: No. The "countless realities" of MWI are not separate worlds, they are all branches of a single system with the same "privileged" laws and even initial conditions. The higher "apotheosis" would be causally separated worlds with different laws of physics, etc., sometimes considered in cosmological speculations, and one can go even higher, as Lewis did in his [modal realism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/david-lewis/#6). The difference with previous cases is that those had actual observations to back them up, while MWI and the rest are, at present, purely theoretical speculations.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I didn't say the earth was the pinnace, I said it was the center, which is consistent with your statement that it is the lowest point.

Comment: @JoWehler - I corrected the typo, thanks! By "anything that can happen does happen" I mean the highly speculative/metaphysical view that reality isn't constrained by what we see but encompasses everything, including countless worlds that are nothing like ours. It's not even remotely empirical, but more along the lines of why WOULD we limit reality to just one instance, surely there is plenty of room for everything when we're talking all of existence.

Comment: @DoubleKnot - thank you for the suggestion. I will have to look into Modal realism b/c I felt my proposal is already pretty out there :)

Comment: @IoannisPaizis - I am not referring to a specific physical theory here, so perhaps I should use a different term (but all seem used up). I am thinking of a much less constrained idea than physics-based multiverses. I'm saying why wouldn't all possible worlds (conceivable by us or otherwise) not be actual universes, just not ours. I don't see a need or basis for such a constraint. Unfortunately, it's also completely untestable ;(

Comment: @Annika My point is that I do not understand what you mean by the question: "What is there that really would stop being (unconstrained) from realizing every single facet of itself?" - The meaning of "anything that can happen does happen" is clear.

Comment: @JoWehler ah, ok. Got confused what you were referring to. I'm saying reality/being, writ large, would have total freedom to be. So why would we say that only certain types of worlds can exist in the totality of being? It seems arbitrary. We can only experience this world, but metaphysically I don't see a basis for denying anything (as long as it is not contradictory) as part of reality.

Comment: @Annika And "writ large"? Sorry for the stupid question, but I am not a native speaker.

Comment: @JoWehler Kristen Berry summarized it well below "the totality of all things", as opposed to our local reality in this universe.

Comment: You said "the special center", clearly alluding to the common English metaphor: "the center of attention", "the central fact", "the science center". It implies something of high importance, especially since the Copernican solar system "took us down a notch" in your own words. This is a very common and very tendentious observation among critics of Western society, but there is no evidence to support it other than the English metaphor that the most important thing is placed at the center.

Comment: @DavidGudeman no, I literally meant center, and "special" was just for effect or the idea that the world of humans was something of interest to the gods, if only for their own entertainment (e.g., Greek gods). The heliocentric theory was controversial at the time, as most scientists did not accept it and the instruments to rule out parallax shift counterarguments to heliocentrism were not available. It was also not a new theory, as the Greeks had a similar concept long before.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I think your reference to " showing that all matter in the universe is the same" isn't heliocentrism as  much as atomism, which has been advanced (see Piertro Redondi, Galileo: Heretic) as the actual reason for the Catholic Church being upset with him (because it was seen as incompatible with the doctrine of transubstantiation)

Comment: Then what did you mean by "taking us down a peg"? In normal English, it means that someone's pride or status has been damaged. Heliocentrism showed that all matter is the same by showing that the earth is just another planet, and thus implying that it was no different from the other planets. In the Aristotelian universe, all matter above the air is a special kind of matter, not found on earth, that is perfect and unchanging.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I didn't use it specifically and only for heliocentrism, but each of those, in their own way, unseats a privilege with regard to some characteristic (centeredness, origins, life-force-having). I was using it as a broad and informal term for this kind of thing.

Comment: We're an atypical species made of atypical chemicals on an atypical planet orbiting an atypical star orbiting an atypical galaxy about 1 part in ten thousand into the likely timeline of galaxies existing. I think you're putting the conclusion before the argument  here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How stable is the Copernican principle, though? [The so-called cosmological "axis of evil"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis_of_evil_(cosmology)), for example, for now can be taken (inconclusively) as some sort of possible contraindication of attempts to situate local regions as "unimportant" or "not special."

At least, the centrality of every human subject, relative to the world as they perceive it, seems to be a manifestation of uniqueness and a transcendental counterexample to the impersonal abstraction of the Copernican principle to an alleged multiverse. But so perhaps one should say either that (A) there is no way to refer specifically to any ultimate totality of things, not even by a phrase like "the multiverse," or (B) the totality of all things is such that local regions are **neither** important nor unimportant in any robust sense (c.f. Kant's take on Zeno's view of the world, that the world-as-a-whole is neither similar nor dissimilar to any "other" thing). Imagine, for example, that *everything* is *trivially* important (if that description be allowed!), or importance itself is "Copernican": why is that not a way to reevaluate, for the better, all local regions, including ours?

One imagines that it is easy to get lost in the supposed power and impressiveness of general and abstract realities, and to lose sight of what is special *everywhere*, both relative to us and to other local domains. To not see the trees for the forest, in other words. **Can we not imagine that there is a universe in the multiverse where everything is special?** Or, at least, we might want to divide especiality into levels, so that regions in some possible world are all lower-level important, even if there are infinitely many copies of this possible world strewn throughout the array of all possible worlds, which would condition all these worlds (and their interior regions) as higher-level less important, etc.

Comment: +1 - wonderful and uplifting take on this :) I think the idea of being "trivially special" is a much more positive viewpoint on the same thing, so we could revise my "principle" to "everything is equally special" (I don't really intend it to be taken too seriously as I just made it up lol) .

Comment: Also, I think you are using inclusive or for your options (A) and (B) because I agree with both!

Comment: Regarding the actual Copernican Principle (and stronger version Cosmological Principle) of cosmology, they represent a much stronger assertion than the mere existence of multiple realities/worlds per (A) + (B). They make strong assumptions about this particular world so as to get around any potential "sampling bias" due to our local vantage point.

Comment: If one looks at the deep space images, we see that galaxies live in very large galactic webs. This suggests a lot of local heterogeneity that my amateur minds see as reasons to doubt that our view is statistically representative across the whole universe. Another area that makes me wonder is the inevitable cosmic horizon that develops in an expanding universe. We can never directly observe these regions and they never interact with us so they could effectively isolate a lot of interesting stuff.

Comment: @Annika I know for reasons of symmetry, there is some expectation of mirror copies of observable regions "way out there," but baryogenesis then is an example of a *broken* symmetry (barring an explanation for the matter/antimatter discrepancy such as [a mirror world projecting from the Big Bang in the opposite temporal direction](https://physicsworld.com/a/our-universe-has-antimatter-partner-on-the-other-side-of-the-big-bang-say-physicists/)), so always expecting symmetry becomes as much a hypothesis to test as an *a priori* condition to *ceteris paribus* insist upon.

Comment: Yeah, symmetry is not a given but feels like a sensible default position unless we have reason to think it's been violated (as your example shows for Baryonic matter).

Answer (score 1):

The astrophysical multiverse is a theory just as much as the [set-theoretic multiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse_(set_theory)) is a theory, in the sense that it is not testable. It is hard to see how such a speculative theory could be seen as the "apotheosis" of heliocentrism, which is eminently testable.

Comment: Apotheosis as the highest realization/conception of a train of thought. a logical zenith vs empirical one. What is metaphysics if not speculation guided by logic?

Comment: Set-theoretic multiverse can also be thought of as "the highest realization/conception of a train of thought. a logical zenith vs empirical one."  Is it then the pinnacle/capstone/apotheosis of heliocentrism?  @Annika

Comment: I’m sure a chase could be made :) not familiar with that one .

Answer (score 1):

Concerning three of your questions:

1. > So why would we say that only certain types of worlds can exist in the
   > totality of being?

   Actually we do not say this. I consider it a great idea of Leibniz
   to argue with the concept of possible words. A possible world is any
   world the existence of which does not contradict logic and its
   principle of non-contradiction.
2. > […] is the link between Copernican ideas and the multiverse something
   > that has been written about before?

   Yes, it has been written out by Brian Green [The Hidden Reality.
   Parallel Universes and the Deep Laws of the Cosmos](https://www.amazon.de/Hidden-Reality-Parallel-Universes-Cosmos/dp/0307265633), see Chap 11,
   “The trek on this book has been toward what may be the capstone
   Copernican correction. […]”
3. > Are there alternatives?

   The consequent alternative is to stop speculating about the concept    of multiverses until we have some evidence from
   astrophysics for the    existence of other universes.

   Penrose
   in some of his talks on    youtube seems to be strictly against
   these speculations when recalling:    First the theory, then its
   confirmation or rejection by experiment or    observation.  This
   position seems a bit conservative. In particular, because    Penrose is a
   scientist who permanently generates new ideas even on    fields
   where he is not an expert.

   Why prohibit speculation - as long    as
   it is not taken as a substitute for scientific theory?

Aside: "Apotheosis" in the title of your question may give the
question a possibly unwanted theistic touch. What about following
Green “Can we consider the multiverse the capstone of the Copernican
correction?”

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize apotheosis has religious connotation - ive seen it used in other context but capstone sounds good too. Will switch.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, these examples have nothing in common except for the subjective and rather forced opinion that they all "took us down a notch".

### Copernicus

It has been claimed that the Heliocentric universe "took us down a notch" because the earth was no longer at the center of the universe, but humans weren't at the center in the thought of the time. Humans were below fire and air and above earth and water. Furthermore, being nearer the center was no special status because the center was the bottom. The top was rarified and perfect; the bottom was full of sin and corruption. So there is no sense in which the Copernican revolution "took us down a notch" except in the revisionism that came centuries later.

### Life is just the proper confluence of (lifeless) physiochemical conditions.

"Taking us down a notch" implies some sort of damage to pride or status, but this conclusion did not damage either. Vitalism wasn't developed to explain why humans are special, it was a theory developed to deal with real scientific observations, no different in principle from other scientific theories like phlogiston or electrons. And it's hard to see how it "takes us down a notch" just because one theoretical force was eliminated. And besides, that, physical reductionism is no longer the dominant view.

### Humans are but the latest iteration of one of many branches of the phylogenetic tree

Alternatively: humans are the **latest** iteration of the most advanced branch of the phylogenetic tree! We are the latest and the best! I don't think it's useful or insightful to attribute subjective values to a scientific theory, but if you do, any value is as good as any other.

### We orbit a star that is just like countless others

There was never a time when the heliocentric universe was the general belief of academics. By the time the heliocentric solar system became the general belief, the question of other suns was already being debated. So this belongs with Copernicus.

### Our galaxy is a middling galaxy among countless galaxies

I'm pretty sure there was never a time when scientists knew what a galaxy is and thought that our galaxy was special, so this is just a change that never happened.

### 5, 6, 7

I have no idea how these theoretical advances "took us down a notch". They made us aware of parameters and possibilities that we had not been aware of before, but how is that a blow to human status or a blow to human pride more so than any other discovery of something we hadn't known before?

Answer (score 0):

Leibniz is the inventor of the multiverse.

**Gilles Deleuze -- Seminar on Leibniz: Philosophy and the Creation of Concepts**

Lecture 02, 22 April 1980
https://deleuze.cla.purdue.edu/lecture/lecture-02-9/

> Imagine this: you dream, and a kind of wizard is there who makes you enter a palace; are you following me? This palace... – so, I am insisting because otherwise, you won’t listen to me: I am only relating a famous text by Leibniz for which I’ll provide the reference later, a very beautiful text which is the *Dream of Apollodorus* -- here we have Apollodorus going to see a goddess, and this goddess leads him into the palace, and looking more closely, this palace is composed of several palaces.

> Leibniz loved that, boxes containing boxes. In [another] text [...] he explained that in the water, there are fish and that in the fish, there is water, and in the water of these fish, there are little fish of fish... It's always infinite analysis. The image of the labyrinth hounds him. He never stops talking about the *labyrinth of continuity*.

> Fine, so there we are, he is led toward a palace, and realizes that this palace is composed of palaces, and it has the form of a pyramid, the point up above, and it is endless. And he notices that each section of the pyramid constitutes a palace.  [...]

> In the highest section of my pyramid, closest to the point, I see a character who is doing something. Right underneath, I see the same character who is doing something else in another location. Even underneath him, [it's] as if all sorts of theatrical productions were playing, and yet completely different ones were playing simultaneously, in each of the palaces, with characters that have common segments. [...]

> This is from a famous text, a huge book by Leibniz called *Theodicy*, namely, God’s justice, divine justice.

> [...] What he means is that at each level, this is a possible world. God chose to bring into existence the extreme world closest to the point of the pyramid. How was he guided in making that choice? We shall see, we must not hurry since this will be a tough problem, what the criteria are for God's choice. But once we've said that he chose a particular world, this world implicated Adam being a sinner; in another world, one can imagine Adam not sinning, all that is simultaneous; in this version of the dream, everything is simultaneous: there is also Adam sinning, but sinning in an entirely different way. [...] Each time there is a world; all these worlds are unfolding simultaneously.

> Something else: each of them is possible. They are *incompossible* with one another, only one can pass into existence. And all of them attempt with all their strength to pass into existence. The vision that Leibniz proposes of the creation of the world by God becomes very stimulating. There are all these worlds that are in God's understanding, and each of which on its own presses forward pretending to pass from the possible into the existent. They have a weight of reality, as a function of their essences. As a function of the essences they contain, they tend to pass into existence. And this is not possible. Why? Because all these worlds are possible, each for itself, but they are not compossible with each other. Hence, existence is like a barricade (barrage). A single combination will pass through. Which one?

> You already can guess Leibniz's splendid response: it will be the best one! What does “the best one” mean? Perhaps not the best one by virtue of a moral theory, but by virtue of a theory of games. And it's not by chance that here as well, Leibniz is one of the founders of statistics and of the calculus of games...

Comment: It started in 600bc in seq. order with: Anaximander, Leucippus, Democritus, Epicurus...

Comment: @IoannisPaizis There are always precedents.

Answer (score 0):

Although I generally agree with @David Gudeman's description of the "Copernican Revolution" in his initial comment, I will go with a more moderate description, from *Wikipedia*.

> ...the phrase "Copernican Revolution" in the 20th century came to be used
> for any (supposed) paradigm shift.

Can such a paradigm shift occur in our times?

Because a paradigm shift like this - where a heaven with angels is transformed to a relativistic universe with complex mathematical structures - means a re-writing of science.

And if our now familiar entities in universe are to be transformed, I can't even imagine into what.

The multiverse is a vague concept: parallel, flat, other, alternate, multiple, plain ... I suspect it is something more profound than that, yet more close to us.

Perhaps dark matter and dark energy are the manifestations of this multiverse that it is just starting to reveal itself...